# Magento : Soap api not working

Tags: magento-1.9, api, soap

Hi i am using magento vesion 1. 9
and i am trying to call magento soap apiv2 using php.

i use the following code.

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://domain/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl=1');
$sessionId = $proxy->login((object)array('username' => 'user', 'apiKey' => 'password'));
$product = $proxy->catalogProductInfo((object)array('sessionId' => $sessionId->result, 'productId' => '27'));
```

i get the session id (i testes it by printing the id)
but when i make a soap call

```
$product = $proxy->catalogProductInfo((object)array('sessionId' => $sessionId->result, 'productId' => '27'));
```

the browser showing "Server error"

api user having full permission in the back end.
but still it is not working. please some one help me to find the solution.

Comment: Please update your question to include the following information: Is there a product with given ID in the catalog? When running the snippet from command line, what is the result? Are there any log entries? Did you enable _WS-I Compliance_ mode via system configuration?

Comment: Yest i have that product with the id "27" and WS-I Compliance is enabled from configuration settings.

Comment: hi Marius,   i am try with your code : https://justpaste.it/577kd and o/p : https://snag.gy/TMBNim.jpg can i get help? @Marius

Comment: @zus. It's not my code. I didn't write this answer

Comment: @Marius really sorry, misunderstanding?

Answer (score 3):

Change the `getProductInfo` call to this

```
$product = $proxy->catalogProductInfo($sessionId->result , 27);
```

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [SOAP-ENV:Client] Error cannot find parameter in /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento_test/api_test.php:4 Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento_test/api_test.php(4): SoapClient->__call('catalogProductI...', Array) #1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento_test/api_test.php(4): SoapClient->catalogProductInfo('2d914eed03509e3...', 27) #2 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento_test/api_test.php on line 4

Comment: Above is the error what i am getting. what will be the problem?

Comment: I don't know what the new problem is

Comment: i think the problem is in my magento package. i tried the same code in new magento install package and it is working fine. i don't know what is the problem in my current magento package. anyway thanks brother for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

## You can try like this way..

```
    $proxy = new SoapClient('http://domain/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl=1');
    $sessionId = $proxy->login((object)array('username' => 'user', 'apiKey' => 'password'));
    $product = $proxy->catalogProductInfo($sessionId,'27','','','productId');
    $proxy->endSession($sessionId);
```

And for better reference see: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/catalog/catalogProduct/catalog_product.info.html